# import data from csv file to datagrid view which has one of checkbox column using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, import-from-csv

I'm using the code shown below to extract contents of cvs file to datagrid view, the following code helped me to extract all content of csv file but while assigning that data to datagrid view giving major problem.
As my csv file have only two text data columns and my datagrid view contains three columns one of them (first column) is checkbox column and remaining are textbox columns. And initially i want my checkbox column as unchecked and by clicking one on the checkbox my entire row should get selected.

**Here is my code:**

```
private void BtnBrowseCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        this.BrowseCSV.Filter = "csv files|*.csv";
        DialogResult result = BrowseCSV.ShowDialog();            

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            CSVFilePathTxtbx.Enabled = true;
            CSVFilePathTxtbx.Text = BrowseCSV.FileName;
        }

        CSVFile = CSVFilePathTxtbx.Text;           
        try
        {
            string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFile);

            //Checks fileContent count > 0 then we have some lines in the file. If = 0 then file is empty
            if (fileContent.Count() > 0)
            {                   
                for (int i = 1; i < fileContent.Count(); i++)
                {
                    string[] rowData = fileContent[i].Split(',');
                    dtgrdvwUsersList.Rows.Add(rowData);
                    //dtgrdvwUsersList.Rows.Add(false, rowData[0], rowData[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        BtnNext.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Is it a wpf or winform related question?

Comment: winform related

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for each of your lines with the added property for the CheckBox

```
public class LineImport
{
    // Name these properties in a meaningful way for your task
    public bool Check {get;set;} 
    public string Text1 {get;set;}
    public string Text2 {get;set;}

    // The constructor receives the line and process it.
    public LineImport(string line)
    {
        // You can add some safety checks here to be sure the right format 
        // has been passed 
        string[] parts = line.Split(',');
        this.Text1 = parts[0];
        this.Text2 = parts[1];
    }
}
```

Now, when you import the CSV lines instead of adding the lines directly to your grid create a `List<LineImport>` and add items to this List

```
List<LineImport> imports = new List<LineImport>();
foreach (string s in File.ReadLines(CSVFile))
{
    LineImport line = new LineImport(s);
    imports.Add(line);
}
```

Finally use the DataSource of your Grid to bind the list

```
BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
source.DataSource = imports;
dtgrdvwUsersList.DataSource = source;
```

As you can see I have also changed the File.ReadAllLines to File.ReadLines to allow the enumeration of the lines without the need to load everything in memory